# Terraform Error: cannot create metastore: Invalid JSON received

Tags: azure, azure-databricks, databricks-unity-catalog, terraform-provider-databricks

I am trying to create databricks metastore using Terraform by following [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs/guides/unity-catalog-azure).

I tried below code:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=3.74.0"
    }
    databricks = {
      source  = "databricks/databricks"
    }
  }
}
provider "databricks" {
   profile = var.databricks_connection_profile (DEFAULT conn profile was valid)
   host = data.azurerm_databricks_workspace.dbwdata.workspace_url
   #token= "*****" (I tried this)
   #config_file = <path of .databrickscfg>  (& this as well)
}
    


resource "databricks_metastore" "this" {
       provider = databricks.accounts
       name     = "mymeta"
       storage_root = format("abfss://%s@%s.dfs.core.windows.net/sandbox",
         "container",
         "samplestorage")
       force_destroy = true
       region        = var.azure_region
       depends_on = [
         module.databricks
        ]
       }
```

But I am getting below error:

> Error: cannot create metastore: Invalid JSON received (1040 bytes):
> <!doctype html>Databricks - Sign
> inYou need to enable JavaScript
> to run this app.

Comment: Are you an account admin? Have you checked the troubleshooting guide? https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs/guides/troubleshooting

Comment: Yes, I am using authentication of service principal which is account admin. I did check troubleshooting guide and used all suggestions in it. But still it's not working

Comment: I updated databricks provider version to 1.29.0, now I am getting different error. "Error: cannot create metastore: Failed to retrieve tenant ID for given token"

Comment: Create Github issue and attache debug logs

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're encountering suggests an issue related to authentication or access to the `Databricks` environment. Make sure it has the required permissions for the `Service Principal` **(Account Admin)** to create a `Meta Store`. follow the [Ms doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/databricks/administration-guide/users-groups/service-principals#--manage-service-principals-in-your-account) about assigning `account admin` to SP.

Here is the updated code to create `Metastore` using `Service Principal`

```json
    terraform {
      required_providers {
        databricks = {
          source = "databricks/databricks"
        }
      }
    }
    provider "azurerm" {
      features {}
    
      client_id       = "SP-App-ID"
      client_secret   = ",SP-secret"
      tenant_id       = "Tenant-ID"
      subscription_id = "Subscription-ID"
    }
    
    data "azurerm_resource_group" "this" {
      name = "Venkat"
    }
    
    data "azurerm_databricks_workspace" "this" {
      name                = "sample-databricks"
      resource_group_name = "Venkat"
    }
    
    provider "databricks" {
      alias               = "accounts"
      host                = "https://accounts.azuredatabricks.net"
      account_id          = "Workspace-account-ID"
      azure_tenant_id     = "Tenant-ID"
      azure_client_id     = "Client-ID"
      azure_client_secret = "secret"
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_databricks_access_connector" "unity" {
      name                = "venkatdatabricksmi"
      resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.this.name
      location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.this.location
      identity {
        type = "SystemAssigned"
      }
    }
    resource "azurerm_storage_account" "unity_catalog" {
      name                     = "thejadatabricksdemo"
      resource_group_name      = data.azurerm_resource_group.this.name
      location                 = data.azurerm_resource_group.this.location
      account_tier             = "Standard"
      account_replication_type = "GRS"
      is_hns_enabled           = true
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_storage_container" "unity_catalog" {
      name                  = "venkat-container"
      storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.unity_catalog.name
      container_access_type = "private"
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "example" {
      scope                = azurerm_storage_account.unity_catalog.id
      role_definition_name = "Storage Blob Data Contributor"
      principal_id         = azurerm_databricks_access_connector.unity.identity[0].principal_id
    }
    
    resource "databricks_metastore" "this" {
      provider = databricks.accounts
      name     = "primary"
      storage_root = format("abfss://%s@%s.dfs.core.windows.net/",
        azurerm_storage_container.unity_catalog.name,
        azurerm_storage_account.unity_catalog.name)
      force_destroy = true
      region        = "eastus"
    }
```

**Terraform apply:**

[image]

After running the code, the meta store has been created in workspace as below.

[image]